# After upgrading to Snow Leopard, now "rvm install 1.9.2" will say "file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)"

Tags: xcode, ruby-on-rails-3

Since `sqlite3` and `mysql2` won't compile on Leopard, so I tried upgrading to Snow Leopard, and then installed XCode 3.2.6, and upgraded to the new rvm 1.5.2, but when I do

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

it will say

```
ld: warning: in dmyext.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture 
    being linked (x86_64)
```

also if I do a `bundle install`, it will say

```
/Users/peter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

is there a civil way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
rvm install 1.9.2-head
```

and it was ok, so I suspected maybe it was due to some object files on the system... anyways, afterwards I did a

```
rvm remove 1.9.2-p0
rvm remove 1.9.2-p180
```

etc... just removing all the 1.9.2, and do an `rvm install 1.9.2` and now it is successful, and `rvm list` will show:

```
   ruby-1.8.6-p399 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p330 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
```

note the `1.8.7` are `i386`, while the `1.9.2` is `x86_64`.